# Rspec create action: expected #count to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, factory-bot

I'm doing some controller testings on my app, and when I test the create action for creating a new service, it gives me this error:  "expected #count to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0"

Theres my spec:

```
  before do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    sign_in @user
  end

  describe "POST #create" do
    context "with valid params" do
      it "creates a new Service" do
        expect {
          post :create, params: { user_id: @user, service: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:service) }
        }.to change(Service, :count).by(1)
      end
    end
  end
```

My factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :service do
    name "Service Test"
    price 1
    time 15
    quantity 2
    user
  end
end
```

My model:

```
class Service
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :user
  field :name, type: String
  field :price, type: Float
  field :time, type: Integer
  field :quantity, type: Integer

  validates :name, :price, :time, :quantity, presence: true
end
```

And the controller:

```
  def create
    @service = Service.new(service_params)
    @service.user = current_user
      if @service.save
        redirect_to services_path
      else
        redirect_to "/services"
      end
  end
```

The error:

```
 Failure/Error:
   expect {
     post :create, params: { user_id: @user, service: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:service) }
   }.to change(Service, :count).by(1)

   expected #count to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0
```

I'm using mongoid, btw. Services is embedded in the User.

Comment: What does `log/test.log` have to say (maybe validation failed)?

Comment: Where is `current_user` defined in controller? May be pass `user_id: @user.id` in params instead of `@user`. If that doesn't work, try replacing `save` with `save!` inside controller code. You will see an exception if the service creation fails.